# How can I forward email based on the send-from address?

Tags: email, smtp, forwarding

So I have a unique situation. I work for an MSP and we host a Unix server in our environment for a customer that sends SMTP to our internal mail server. The problem is on this unix server, there are some applications which send mail to person@customer.com and some applications which send mail to myteam@msp.com. These applications live and work together so I can only configure SMTP settings in one spot.

My thought: Could I use Sendmail or Postfix to look for the send from address and forward accordingly? Like a conditional forwarder of sorts?

Example: mail has a send-from address of *@customer.com and goes to their mail server for delivery and mail with a send-from address of *@msp.com goes to our mail server?

Comment: Whatever mailer you are already using should already do this. What mailer are you using? What is its configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posfix supports selecting relay base on sender address, see
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

sendmail supports something similar but it requires sendmail.cf fixes not supported by sendmail.org.